# Why does xcode think my classobject property is an int?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there something I am missing or is this a bug in Xcode? I cant even run the code since i get a error message.

```
// Class1.m

-(void)somemethod{
    ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    [viewcont setWhatview:self]; // here i get the error message;
}

//viewcontroller.h
@property Class1 *Whatview;
```

error message I get:

```
implicit conversion of an Object to int * is disallowed in arc.
```

Comment: Should you not have `@property Class1 *Whatview;` ? And please name properties with a lower case first letter.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: implicit conversion of an Object to int * is disallowed in arc.

Comment: Where is the error message being reported? Also, can you show the files for `Class1`.

Comment: Can i use id instead for this purpose?

Comment: Add @class Class1 into viewcontroller,h or #import "Class1.h" in viewcontroller.h

Comment: You need to show more of your code.  Have you `#include viewcontroller.h` in Class1.m ?  Do you have an @synthesize for the `Whatview` property or using automatic synthesis?